minikube connection with lens

Pasted complete config file in open lens + button , but after that I am receiving this error
Do not think,  the error is related to certificates because same certificates working inside minikube .
Do not think,  the error is related to certificates because same certificates working inside minikube .

Please include code/errors as text and not as images.
